# How to use Table Valued parameter in Microsoft SQL Server with Node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I have a NodeJS function that interacts with a SQL Server database using the mssql library. This function creates a new group if it doesn't already exist, and populate the group members with the specified user IDs. It checks if the group exists by array of users in a group. I am getting an error

> The procedure "sp_executesql" has no parameter named "@UserIds".

Looks like Table Valued parameter is not supported.
Is there a way to overcome this issue? Thank you in advance.

code:

```
async function createOrGetGroup(group: any, users: number[]) {
  try {
    let connection = await sql.connect(config);
    // Create a table-valued parameter (TVP) for user IDs
    const tvp = new sql.Table();
    tvp.columns.add('UserId', sql.Int);

    // Populate the TVP with user IDs
    users.forEach((userId) => {
      tvp.rows.add(userId);
    });
    console.log("Right before the query statement")
    // Check if a group with the specified users already exists
    const existingGroup = await connection.request()
      .input('UserIds', sql.TVP, tvp ) // Use the TVP here
      .query(`
        SELECT g.Id AS GroupId
        FROM ${groupTable} AS g
        JOIN ${groupMembersTable} AS gm ON g.Id = gm.GroupId
        LEFT JOIN @UserIds AS u ON gm.UserId = u.UserId
        GROUP BY g.Id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gm.UserId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @UserIds)
          AND COUNT(u.UserId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @UserIds)
      `);
    console.log("checking if passed this point or exception was thrown")
    if (existingGroup.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      // A group with the specified users already exists, return its ID
      await connection.close();
      return existingGroup.recordsets[0][0].GroupId;
    } else {
      // Create a new group
      const newGroup = await connection.request()
        .input('name', sql.NVarChar, group.name)
        .input('teams', sql.Int, group.teams)
        .query(`
          INSERT INTO ${groupTable} ([name], teams)
          OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
          VALUES (@name, @teams)
        `);

      // Populate VoipGroupMembers with the specified users
      for (const userId of users) {
        await connection.request()
          .input('groupId', sql.Int, newGroup.recordsets[0][0].Id)
          .input('userId', sql.Int, userId)
          .query(`
            INSERT INTO ${groupMembersTable} (groupId, userId, joinedDate, leftDate)
            VALUES (@groupId, @userId, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL)
          `);
      }

      await connection.close();

      // Return the ID of the newly created group
      return newGroup.recordsets[0][0].Id;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error; // Throw the original error for better error information
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks correct from the docs https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/tree/3d2025729e21c7f4a9ef43289fa0e819e6336037#table-valued-parameter-tvp except that I think you need to also specify the Table Type name using `tvp.name`, see https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/125#issuecomment-239672739 What version of node-mssql are you using?

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen TVPs used with `.query()` before and am not near a dev computer to test currently. Normally you'd use TVPs with `.execute()` because the invoked stored procedure needs to define the TVP parameter with the `READONLY` keyword. The `mssql` library would need to be doing something like this on its `.query()` method to make it work with `sp_executesql`... https://dbfiddle.uk/5egMK5ZK